# Values are not updated in a PowerShell function

Tags: function, powershell, variables

I made a code to get some variables and values from a TXT file. The code looks like that, and it works as expected:

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\File.txt" | ? {$_ -match "="} | % {
    $Item = $_.Split('=')
    if (Test-Path Variable:\$($Item[0])) {
        Set-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1]
        Write-Host $Item[0] $Item[1]
    } else {
        New-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1] -Force
    }
}
Write-Host $IPaddress
Write-Host $Hostname
```

The file.txt looks like that:

```
IPaddress=192.168.1.100
Hostname=server01
```

So from this example, I get the variables `$IPaddress` and `$Hostname` with their values from the TXT file.
However, as I need to use this this code quite often, or because the values in the TXT file are updated, or to get it from a different TXT files, I included it in a function:

```
function GetInfo {
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    Get-Content $FilePath | ? {$_ -match "="} | % {
        $Item = $_.Split('=')
        if (Test-Path Variable:\$($Item[0])) {
            Set-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1]
            Write-Host $Item[0] $Item[1]
        } else {
            New-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1] -Force
        }
    }
}

GetInfo -FilePath "C:\Temp\File.txt"

Write-Host $IPaddress
Write-Host $Hostname
```

And here is the issue! First time I execute the script no worries, the variables and values are gotten properly. However, if I modify the values in the TXT file (for example the IP address changes to 192.168.1.200) and execute the script again, I can see in the function itself that the new IP is gotten properly from the `Write-Host $Item[0] $Item[1]`, but at the end, the value of `$IPaddress` will not be updated (`Write-Host $IPaddress` will still display 192.168.1.100).

Comment: Your variables are created in a local scope and thus don't exist in the global scope. You can explicitly specify the scope when creating a variable. However, a better and much simpler way would be to simply dot-source another PowerShell script with the variable definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the variables should be declared as global. That can be done in `Set-Variable` method like below,

```
function GetInfo {
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    Get-Content $FilePath | ? {$_ -match "="} | % {
        $Item = $_.Split('=')
        if (Test-Path Variable:\$($Item[0])) {
            Set-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1] -Scope global
           #Write-Host $Item[0] $Item[1]
        } else {          
            New-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1] -Force
        }
    }
}

GetInfo -FilePath "C:\Temp\File.txt"

Write-Host $IPaddress
Write-Host $Hostname
```

In the above code you can see that i have mentioned the scope as global. Try that one. It should solve your issue.

> Set-Variable -Name $Item[0] -Value $Item[1] -Scope global

Comment: Thanks both of you, the issue is solved, I really did not think about the scope... Thanks again!!!

Comment: Happy to help @Johann!